# Grouping about 100 Radio Buttons

Tags: python, pyqt5, radio-button, buttongroup

I'm trying to create a multiple-choice test with approximately 100 questions in it. In this example, I give you a group of radio buttons. I solved creating multiple radio buttons with this code. However, I want to group these selections.

I found a soultion in this link : [https://www.delftstack.com/tutorial/pyqt5/pyqt5-radiobutton/#:~:text=setChecked(True)-,PyQt5%20QRadiobutton%20Group,are%20connected%20to%20different%20functions](https://www.delftstack.com/tutorial/pyqt5/pyqt5-radiobutton/#:%7E:text=setChecked(True)-,PyQt5%20QRadiobutton%20Group,are%20connected%20to%20different%20functions).

However, they didn't create radio buttons with 'for' loop. What should I do about this?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ornek(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.toggles = []
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.h_box = QGridLayout()


        for i in range (4):
            self.btngroup = QButtonGroup()
            for j in range (4):
                if j % 4 == 0:
                    self.btn = QRadioButton("A", self)
                elif j % 4 == 1:
                    self.btn = QRadioButton("B", self)
                elif j % 4 == 2:
                    self.btn = QRadioButton("C", self)
                else:
                    self.btn = QRadioButton("D", self)


                text = self.btn.text()
                self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, text=text: print("\nclicked--> {}".format(text)))
                self.h_box.addWidget(self.btn,i,j,1,1)
            self.lay.addLayout(self.h_box)

        self.setLayout(self.lay)



        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Çıkış Projesi")
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pencere = Ornek()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? What do you mean by "I want to group these selections"? You are already creating 4 groups of 4 radio, what is it that you cannot do?

Comment: I mean, when I choose new answer , i.e if ;I choose B in second question, my first question selection is disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created a QButtonGroup but you don't use it, your code can be rewritten as:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.toggles = []
    lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
    h_box = QGridLayout()
    lay.addLayout(h_box)

    for i in range(4):
        btngroup = QButtonGroup(self)
        btngroup.buttonClicked.connect(lambda btn: print(btn.text()))

        for j in range(4):
            btn = QRadioButton()
            btngroup.addButton(btn)
            h_box.addWidget(btn, i, j, 1, 1)

            if j % 4 == 0:
                btn.setText("A")
            elif j % 4 == 1:
                btn.setText("B")
            elif j % 4 == 2:
                btn.setText("C")
            else:
                btn.setText("D")

        
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 250)
    self.setWindowTitle("Çıkış Projesi")
    self.show()
```

Comment: I actually tried to add buttons to the group button but it was the wrong place (after the second for). Now, I saw it, a basic silly mistake. Thanks for your solution, it helped me a lot!